# How many possible invalid AIS message body combinations are there for a specific checksum?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, permutations, combinations

According to the [CATB AIS Specification](http://catb.org/gpsd/AIVDM.html), there is a 2 digit checksum to check an incoming AIS message for validity:

Here is a sample AIS message:

> AIVDM,1,1,,B,177KQJ5000G?tO`K>RA1wUbN0TKH,0*5C

The actual AIS message body is the payload which is:

> 177KQJ5000G?tO`K>RA1wUbN0TKH,0

And the checksum is on the end which is:

> 5C

Each character placeholder can be a total of 64 different characters. The checksum, however, is tested using a [weird XOR calculation](https://rietman.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/how-to-calculate-the-nmea-checksum/) which may skew the calculation using finite math. My question is, how many invalid message payload combinations exist for each checksum? That is, if the checksum only has 64^2 or 4,096 combinations, then there are X chunks of payload combinations that match each checksum, and since only 1 of those are valid per AIS message the others would constitute invalid messages (that would still pass the checksum).

Comment: For the other people answering this question the checksum is calculated by preforming a rolling bitwise xor on byte size blocks.

Comment: Also you might wish to consider that this check sum can't detect transposed characters which means that a corrupted payload may pass the checksum and also be valid but contain errors.

Comment: That would be in addition to payloads with valid characters? Am I correct to assume the checksum is virtually useless as its total combinations are nowhere near the total combinations of the payload?

Comment: Is the string length fixed length?  Because you can insert an unlimited number of null characters (all bits zero) and an unlimited even number of (all bits one) chars.

Answer (score -1):

You can view the payload as being 8 bit strings of length N where N is the length of the playload.  The first bit string being all the most significant digits, the next the second most significant digits etc.

A parity check will eliminate half of these possibilities. So the number of
possible passing strings will be $8(2^{n-1})$. Note many of the passing payloads will contain strings with characters outside the given alphabet.

Comment: If the payload is 30 characters with 64 different letter possibilities each, wouldn't it be 64^30 / 64^2 ?

Comment: While 64 characters are permitted, each character is represented as an 8 bit byte.  So errors could corrupt the bit pattern into something that represents something other then a permitted letter but still check sum correctly.  Also the check sum is represented as 2 hex digits so it is 16^2 rather then 64^2.

Comment: So assuming before checking the sum, we first check the string to make sure all the characters are in range, then it would be  64^30 / 16^2? And if the checksum only has 256 combinations, doesn't that make it almost useless?

Comment: Yes it does make it almost useless.

Comment: For the message above excluding invalid characters, I am getting 6 sexdecillion, does that sound right?